# When submitting a form to a remote php script using ajax, is it possible to check what errors are occurring on the remote script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a field that I am submitting to a remote php script. There is an error occurring on that script. Is it possible to display what is the error so as to append it?

This is what I have:

```
<script>
<!--
var all="My information";
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myurl.php",
data: all,
success: function(html){
if(html == 'done'){
alert("working");
}else{
alert("something is wrong");
}
}
});
-->
</script>
```

I am receiving the alert **something is wrong** so I know that it is an error with my PHP script. Is there a way I can have this error displayed?

Comment: Where do you want to display the error?

Comment: @vivek anywhere. I just need to see what errors are occuring so that I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to return the errors on the myurl.php. do this:

Example:

```
success: function(server_response)
{
 document.getElementById("resultdata").style.display = "block";
$('#resultdata').html(server_response).show();

}
```

make a division on your current page named resultdata and set display: none. it will only show if you have an error

you will need to use if and else statements on your myurl.php.

example:

```
if($a == $b)
  {
    echo "sucess";
  }
  else
    {
       echo " failed";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can better print what is in `html`. If display errors is set to on, and there are errors in script they will appear in response.

If errors are not displayed, you can add following code to turn error display on

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Comment: Just `alert(html)` before the `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Set suitable `error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string` in your php.ini file. In my case, I use `<div class="serverfault">` and `</div>`.

Then, search the result for a regex based around this string, like so: `/<div class="serverfault">([\d\D]+?)</div>/g`

You can now display the errors that occurred.

I went one step further, and added "Ignore" and "Abort" buttons (or in the case of a Fatal Error, "Abort" only). If the "Ignore" button is pressed, the regex is run again as a `replace` to remove the PHP error message, and the remaining string is treated as the AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the errors in the error log file by changing the php.ini file.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors

Comment: I did this and it displayed what is in the brackets **something is wrong**. I need to see the exact error on the page. e.g. warning: unknown column in line 12.

Comment: Modified my answer Bryan, log the errors in the error log file by modifying the php.ini, this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell with the information you provided.

What I usually do is validate the input *before* I process it.
If somethings wrong you can return a json encoded answer with a custome error message else you return a success message.

```
if(! validateMail($_POST['mail']){
    echo json_encode(array('state' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid mail'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('state' => 'ok'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a quick and dirty way to check what is wrong with the script change your if statement to this:

```
if(html == 'done'){
alert("working");
}else{
alert(html);
alert("something is wrong");
}
```

Although if you are looking to actually display an error to your user then you'll want to display `html` in a form other than `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

with my library phery, errors and exceptions and decoupled from regular response, and they all have their own callbacks. you may check the error in http://phery-php-ajax.net/demo.php 
you may also catch AJAX only error in the code using the `error_reporting` config, scroll down to "Custom error reporting for a bit of code". Also click the "See PHP Code" to see how it's done.

An exception, like in a try/catch block inside PHP, you would return a `PheryResponse::factory()->exception()` with a descriptive exception for your client.

This way you can leave ALL the error checking where it belongs, in the SERVER, and the client just do what's supposed to do, DISPLAY the server state.

```js
$('a#click-me')
// Make the link ajaxified
.phery('make', 'remote-function')
// Bind the events to the element
.on({
  'phery:exception': function(event, message){ 
    alert(message);
  },
  'phery:json': function(event, data){
    // deal with your json data
  }
});
```

The PHP side would be

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'remote-function' => function($data){
     $r = new PheryResponse;
     try {
       // fill your JSON data array
       $r->json($json); // deliver the JSON
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       $r->exception($e->getMessage()); // Exception, send the error to the client
     }
     return $r;
  }
))->process();
```